# SQL Foreign Key in Another Database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, cross-database

I am currently creating a database at work that is essentially a child of another database. When our clients get our software they get a database, lets call it MasterBase. This database contains schema of two different smaller databases put together, lets call them MasterC and MasterF.

My job is to take all the schema that pertain to MasterF and put them in their own database. The problem is there are a lot of references to tables and views in MasterC. To work around this I will add a property that will pair MasterF with MasterC so that in my .NET solution I should be able to do things like:

Table tableName.... (table being created in MasterF) 
References .... MasterC.dbo.tableC (table in MasterC)

However, in SQL this raises the error: MSG 1763 Cross-Database foreign key references are not supported.

I have read the most common work around is to add a trigger, but seeings how this is not that safe and there are MANY instances of this I was wondering if there was another way, perhaps a stored procedure or something of the sort.

If a trigger is really the best/only way and I MUST add a trigger to every table that has this problem, how would I go about writing this trigger, I know a little SQL but am hardly proficient.

Please Help!

Comment: What is the actual code that is raising the error?

Comment: The FK's can't go with, and writing a battery of triggers to do the same is going to be a headache. Is the reasoning behind this to separate out files? You can allocate tables to alternate DB files and independently move them.

Comment: The purpose of separating the databases is so they can be built individually. So some clients may need both and some may only need one or the other.. The tool I am creating will account for this by simply not build the schema referencing MasterC if the client needs a standalone MasterF. However, if they need both, MasterC is guaranteed to exist so can be referenced.

Comment: Why don't you build the appropriate kind of database: C, F and C+F?

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, but I can't build F without referencing some schema of C... C+F was the standard because they are strongly related, this is a new feature for clients I am working on.

I guess I don't understand what you're asking because that's pretty much what I was trying to ask..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Triggers (as you mention)...
- Database Partitioning...
- Duplicate the tables from MasterC (are they transactional?  How often are they updated? Does MasterC need the updates?  If so, can you allow for the copies to be updated every 24-hours, etc. via a "Job"?)

Per your last comment about individual builds, I guess I'd say that the threshold for when a client "needs" both is when they...well, "need" both.  Sounds almost like you need a 3rd schema, for tables in MasterC that do NOT reference MasterF, for those clients you're categorizing as not needing both.

BTW -- this is all about referential integrity, yes?  There are other strategies you could employ toward that goal, besides 'relationships'.

*EDIT*

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger ON myTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM OtherDatabase.otherschema.othertable F
           JOIN inserted AS i 
           ON F.KeyYouAreLookingFor = i.KeyYouHave)
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Lookup Value Not Found -- Insert Failed', 16, 1);
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN 
END;
```

Comment: How would i build a table that references another table with out a foreign key relationship. 

About the third schema you mentioned, I will add extended properties to the schema which can be used to determine when the table need be built. I also cannot add the tables from MasterC to MasterF, that almost completely defeats the purpose. 

I'm not sure about database partitioning, as far as what it is, like I said I'm a bit of a 'noob'.

Comment: You do need a FK to query. It allows the DBMS to enforce that values in the referencing table appear in the referenced table and to optimize. If you have synonymns you can at least CHECK that the projection on referencing columns is a subset of the projection on referenced column. The fact that the referenced columns of a FK should also be either a key or unique is redundant anyway (logically but not for optimization).

Comment: @user3662475 -- personally, I'd be inclined to use triggers -- it seems like the most reliable option.  I've edited my answer so you can see how that might be accomplished.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will certainly use triggers as it seems like the best way. Also, thank you for the example, as I said I am new to the SQL scene and would probably have spent a lot of time learning how to write them.. Much obliged!